# Magento DB is filled with \\r\\n\\ .How to remove them?

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9

This issue happened when the site transfered from  a plesk server to a cpanel.
All the site was filled with \r\n\r\n\ .I deleted all of them inside in the site but DB is filled with them. The issue is that when you make and new order in the NAME LAST NAME fields they appear in front of them \r\n\.

[EDIT] Transfer was made manually (downloaded in my pc and then uploaded via ftp) Database imported via ssh

I am not sure for this but i think that the DB was like this before transfer but this doesn't made any problem in the site.

Can someone help me how to remove them?

Comment: Re-transfer the site (and ditch Plesk/cPanel). Something didn't transfer right and there's likely to be lots of other issues as a result.

Comment: don't use transfer tool - export database with mysqldump and import from command line :)

Comment: The transfer was made manually not by tool. Re transfer is not possible sadly..

Comment: @1078fin Then you likely have a completely wrecked database. If your tool has broken even so simple a thing as a line break consider what else it may have screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

I literally had the same thing today setting up a local version. I thought it was an environment issue, until I compared the content in a DB entry to my remote.

I had done a quick dump from PHPMyAdmin, as soon as I connected via Sequel Pro and got a dump that way, all was fine. This would mirror what @ceejayoz is recommending, just different way.